# How to generate a 2 column display of a list in RDLC

Tags: wpf, winforms, rdlc

I am absolutely new to RDLC using wpf. I am embedding RDLC using `WindowsFormsHost` control in my WPF window.

My requirement is to display a list using only 2 or n columns and multiple rows, as I want print out in that format only. In WPF we can show such a display using `WrapPanel (n columns) or UniformGrid`.

I used `Tablix` which is present in RDLC and can easily my list as a single column, but how to show that list in 2 or n columns ?

See example output below :

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use table for multiple column. 
In this you can add multiple columns.

[image: Check in this screenshot.]

Comment: For this you can use list and place text box inside it.